# R Keras Error: Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ValueError: No data provided

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

Running R V4

When attempting to run a model with a pre-trained word-embedding, I'm getting the error: Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
ValueError: No data provided for "dense_16". Need data for each key in: ['dense_16']

I've seen several questions dealing with this issue, and it seems to deal with data being of the wrong type and there for can't be coerced by TensorFlow to the correct form. That being said, as seen in the last bit of code, I've forced my code into matrix as vector form as seems to be the suggestion, and am still getting the error.

The code to create the word embedding is pulled directly from chapter 6 of Chollet and Allaire's Deep learning with R, so I'm fairly confident in that. The only change was my data. The data is text from assignments/exams and the students scores on the data. You'll notice that exam.scores and class.scores include 27 students (rows), but only one row is being fed into the NN.

```
setwd("C:/Users/tanne/Desktop/RData/Glove")
lines<-readLines("C:/Users/tanne/Desktop/RData/Glove/glove.6B.100d.txt")
embeddings_index<-new.env(hash = TRUE,parent = emptyenv())
gc()
for(i in 1:length(lines)){
  line<-lines[[i]]
  values <- strsplit(line," ")[[1]]
  word <- values[[1]]
  embeddings_index[[word]]<-as.double(values[-1])
  
  }

#dim from Glove file
embedding_dim <- 100

embedding_matrix <- array(0, c(max_words, embedding_dim))
gc()
for (word in names(word_index)) {
  index <- word_index[[word]]
  if (index < max_words) {
    embedding_vector <- embeddings_index[[word]]
    if (!is.null(embedding_vector))
      # Words not found in the embedding index will be all zeros.
      embedding_matrix[index+1,] <- embedding_vector
  }
}


model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_embedding(input_dim = max_words, output_dim = embedding_dim, 
                  input_length = maxlen) %>% 
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") #%>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

summary(model)

get_layer(model, index = 1) %>% 
  set_weights(list(embedding_matrix)) %>% 
  freeze_weights()

model %>% compile(
  optimizer="rmsprop",
  loss="binary_crossentropy",
  metrics=c("acc")
)

history<-model %>% fit(
  as.matrix(class.text),c(class.scores[1,]),
  epochs=20,
  batch_size=32,
  validation_data=list(as.matrix(exam.text),c(exam.scores[1,]))
)
```

And the error:

````
  File "C:\Users\tanne\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1278, in fit
    validation_split=validation_split)
  File "C:\Users\tanne\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 917, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\Users\tanne\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 130, in standardize_input_data
    'for each key in: ' + str(names))```
````

To show the state of the data:

```
> dim(exam.scores)
[1] 27 32
> dim(class.scores)
[1]   27 1492
> dim(exam.text)
[1]  32 500
> dim(exam.scores)
[1] 27 32
> class(exam.scores)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(class.scores)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(exam.text)
[1] "matrix" "array" 
> class(class.text)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

I'm thankful for any suggestions or just more tips for debugging.